# What do I use for better performance : vector of pairs or 2d array?

Tags: c++

What should I use for better performance : `vector<pair<string, string>>` or `string myArray[10][2]` (10 is example number, 2 because I need to store 2 strings), or there is some better way I should stick to?

Comment: Measure it and find out.

Comment: I would expect if there are only 10 elements the difference is going to be so small you can't measure it reliably very easily. Meaning this type of optimization is likely a waste of effort.

Comment: Why not a structure for the pair of strings, for better semantic coupling? To me this really feels like you're concentrating on the wrong bits about your program. Try to write a good, readable, maintainable and working program before worrying about performance. If you have some performance requirements, and the program doesn't match them then measure and profile to find the top *two* bottlenecks and fix only those (with enough documentation and comments to explain the optimizations and why the optimization was needed).

Comment: std::array tends to have about same performance as raw array; std::vector tends to have slightly weaker performance.

Comment: @ÖöTiib In what way?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but pair was created for storing 2 elements, why do I have to create structure for that purpose? I am new in C++ as you could see and can ask  probably strange questions for experienced devs

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings std::array has one indirection less than std::vector and does not involve dynamic memory management.

Comment: When testing, make sure you test a *optimized* build of your code. Testing unoptimized debug builds is rather pointless as they don't accurately reflect real-life performance (and are rather slow, often in surprising places that optimized builds eliminate completely).

Comment: @ÖöTiib Lookup does not involve dynamic memory management. It does involve a dereference, I'll give you that. It'll be very, very hard to observe a penalty there though. As for `std::array` vs raw array, it's literally just a wrapper around a raw array; the difference is only in the type system.

Comment: Semantic coupling, as I mentioned. A `std::pair` is just two relatively unrelated values. If the two values belong as a single object you really should create a structure or a class.That also allows you to create functions specifically tailored for that object, instead of being callable with just any pair of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better performance, you should use the one which is faster.

If neither is significantly faster, then you should use the one that is more convenient.

You can find out which is faster in your program by measuring. It could be either, depending on how you use them.

> or there is some better way I should stick to?

In some cases, it could potentially be more efficient to allocate the memory of all strings in one massive block instead of using separate `std::string` objects.

---

P.S. `std::pair` is rarely a good choice. Usually, it is better to use a custom class where you can give descriptive names for the two subobjects.

Answer (score -1):

`std::pair` and vector means that you will only have to iterate through the container one time to get all values using.

```
for(auto& p : vector)
     ...do stuff
```

if you use a 2d array you would have to use two for loops to iterate over the strings.
i might be wrong though

Comment: There's nothing inherently slow about a loop, and a loop over two elements would probably be unwrapped anyway. The access pattern should be about the same.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out @AsteroidsWithWings. did not know that